# SSH issues when upgrading MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, openssh

I have an app that's been running on MariaDB 10.1.41 for a while now. Recently a dev database was upgraded to 10.2.33, and now it won't allow us to use self-signed certificates for SSH. We need inter-server communication for replication, and up until now these certs have been fine.
I've been trying to find out what in this upgrade might have caused this, but everything I've been able to find so far suggests that self-signed certificates probably shouldn't have worked at all.
We did have some other issues following the update - mostly caused by strict mode being enabled by default - these have been resolved, but I've been unable to find anything suggesting why our certs no longer work.

Comment: You mean SSL/TLS, not SSH (Secure SHell) I assume?

Comment: Yes, my mistake.

Comment: Self signed certificates should be fine, but if ssl-verify-server-cert is enabled o the client side certificate verification fails if the host name in the certificate doesn't match the actual server hostname. That check is not enabled by default though, at least not in the "mysql" command line client


see also https://mariadb.com/kb/en/secure-connections-overview/#server-certificate-verification

Maybe that is the actual problem you are running into?

Without knowing actual configuration, error message, and how exactly the certificates were generated it is hard to tell what's wrong

Comment: When we add the ssl config lines to the [client] section of my.cnf, the error message I'm seeing on command line is :
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: self signed certificate

If I run openssl verify -CAfile on the certs, it reports :
error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate

But these are the same certs we were using before the MariaDB upgrade.